# radio button select only one at a time and insert radio button value in database

Tags: php, html, opencart

I am working on opencart 1.5 . I am having a problem  in radio button selection which selects only one value at a time but not more than one and post it's value in database.When I insert data then radio button value default "0" save in database. So help me to solve this problem.I had posted my code below which is on the admin side in opencart.

***Coding***

```
    <div id="tab-video">
   <table id="video" class="list">  
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_video_group; ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_property; ?></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </thead> 
        <?php $video_row = 0 ?>
        <?php if (count($product_videos) > 0) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($product_videos as $product_video) { ?>
        <?php $video_row++ ; ?>
        <tbody id="video-row<?php echo $video_row; ?>">

             <?php if($video_row == 1) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_unset_video?></td>
                <td>
                <?php if($product_video['base_image'] == '0') { ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" checked="checked" value="0"/>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" value="0"/>
                <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            <?php } ?>

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_video_label?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <input type="text" name="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_label]" id="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_label]" value="<?php echo $product_video['video_label']; ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>  

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_youtube_id?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <input type="text" name="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_youtube]" id="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_youtube]" value="<?php echo $product_video['video_youtube']; ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_set_video?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php if($product_video['base_image'] == '1') { ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" checked="checked" value="0"/>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" value="0"/>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <a onclick="$('#video-row<?php echo $video_row; ?>').remove();" class="button">
                        <?php echo $button_remove; ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="new_row_id" id="new_row_id" value="<?php echo $video_row; ?>"  />
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php $video_row++ ; ?>
        <tbody id="video-row<?php echo $video_row; ?>">
              <tr>
                <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_unset_video?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" value="0" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_video_label?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <input type="text" name="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_label]" id="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_label]" value=""/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>  

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_youtube_id?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <input type="text" name="product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_youtube]" id="product_videp[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][video_youtube]" value=""/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <?php echo $entry_set_video?>
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                    <input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td class="left">
                </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
         <input type="hidden" name="new_row_id" id="new_row_id" value="<?php echo $video_row; ?>"  />
        <?php } ?>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="left"><a onclick="addvideo();" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_video; ?></a></td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     function addvideo() {
 var video_row = $('#new_row_id').val();
 var new_video_row = video_row + 1 ;

html  = '<tbody id="video-row' + new_video_row + '">';
html += '  <tr>';
html += '  <td class="left" height="10px"></td>';
html += '  <td class="left" height="10px"></td>';
html += '  <td class="left" height="10px"></td>';
html += '  </tr>';
html += '  <tr>';
html += '  <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_video_label?></td>';
html += '  <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_video[' + new_video_row + '][video_label]" value=""/></td>';
html += '  <td></td>';
html += '  </tr>';
html += '  <tr>';
html += '  <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_youtube_id?></td>';
html += '  <td class="left"><input type="text" name="product_video[' + new_video_row + '][video_youtube]" value=""/></td>';
html += '  <td></td>';
html += '  </tr>';
html += '  <tr>';
html += '  <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_set_video?></td>';
html += '  <td><input type="radio" name="$product_video[<?php echo $video_row; ?>][base_image]" value="1"/></td>';
html += ' <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#video-row' + new_video_row +'\').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '</tbody>';
$('#video tfoot').before(html);

$('#new_row_id').val(new_video_row);
     }</script>
```

I have also attached image below for reference
[image]

Comment: remove the $ in `<input type="radio" name="$product_video`

Comment: thanks Deonia now radio button value inserted in database but not select only one radio button at a time when edit this form.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to be able to select/check multiple radio buttons ? If so, you need checkbox buttons, not radio buttons.

Comment: no i want to select only one radio button at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select one radio button at once, you have to give the all radio button's name same.
Else you have to do js trick if one is selected deselect others.

Comment: if i give all radio button name same then radio button value not post in database and default "0" store. i not know how solve this problem and how post value in opencart...help me....thanks in advance.

Comment: if you give all radio button name same, then when you post it will just post the value of the radio which is selected. You can get it by $_POST['radio_name']

Comment: can you describe more about your problem.

Comment: i give name of radio button same and when i add more than one row and select one row radio button then this radio button value update in all row in database.

Comment: Please don't change the name of the radio.and use the below js.
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input:radio').click(function(event) {    
    $('input:radio').not(this).attr('checked', false);
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
   });});

Comment: please vote up the comment so that other users also get this useful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29574/discussion-between-nikunj-patel-and-supriti-panda)

Comment: Thanks @Supriti Panda for help and your suggestion help me complete module of opencart and i have completed my module.